# How to center a TextView in the header of a CardView?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to center a TextView in the header of a CardView as a "discount tag". How can I create a layout like this in Android?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Hello Alert"
                    android:elevation="6dp"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:paddingStart="16dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                    android:background="@color/md_green_300"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/materialCardView4"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/materialCardView4"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/materialCardView4" />
            
                <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                    android:id="@+id/materialCardView4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/color_gray"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
            
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> **Output**

[image: Output]

Comment: Thank you, it was exactly what I expected.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ConstraintLayout` to overlap one view to another. This is the best way to do it

for example, I did:-

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".ui.contactdeatail.ContactDetailActivity">

        <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:id="@+id/view"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:background="#00E676"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"/>

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/krishna"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="132dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.511"
                android:id="@+id/circleImageView"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/user_name"
                android:lines="1"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view"
                android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.511"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                tools:text="Krishna Sony"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/circleImageView"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/cardView">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_call_black_24dp"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view2"/>

                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/mobile"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        tools:text="+91-9981048926"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"/>

                <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:id="@+id/view2"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:background="@color/light_gray"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mobile"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>

                <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_mail_black_24dp"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view2"/>

                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/email"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        tools:text="krishnasony97@gmail.com"/>

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"
                android:id="@+id/back_button"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/call"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
                app:cardMaxElevation="12dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="120dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.234">

            <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_call_black_24dp"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[Check this image output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7QA2.jpg)

Comment: Thank you for the help, but in your example, the image is only centered due to the applied margin. I need to centralize without applying margins.

Comment: you can do it just set constraint top, bottom, end, and start to reference of your card view

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution for your case. It'll have a little bit trick ^^
With constraint layout, i will create a dummy view that center your text in vertical
Then my cardview will constraintTopToBottom with that dummy view.
Hope that help ^^

```
<View
    android:background="@color/colorTransparent"
    android:id="@+id/dummy"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tv"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tv"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"/>

<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorLightGrey"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    android:background="@color/colorGreen"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/dummy"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"/>

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:elevation="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:text="Hello Alert"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@color/colorGreen"
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVDDf.png)